# Can I decompile pyc (compiled by python2.7) to py?

Tags: python, decompiler

CVS deleted one of my files when I updated my project before commit. All that I've got now is a .pyc file compiled by Python 2.7. How can I decompile it?

Comment: There's Murphy's law at work...

Comment: Is it not there in a previous commit?

Comment: No, it isn't. This happened because in past i created file with a same name and after that deleted it.

Comment: Thank God! I found source file in PyCharm local history.
Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This is old but may still work:  http://www.crazy-compilers.com/decompyle/

A newer tool can be found here:  http://www.depython.net/

Your can also try this one (but it doesn't work on iterators):  http://sourceforge.net/projects/unpyc/

Comment: This tools works fine but only for python 2.6 and older. I think i should just re-write this file... :(

Answer (score 0):

You may try ***[Easy Python Decompiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/)***. It's based on Decompyle++ and Uncompyle2.

Note: I am the author of the above tool.